# Python2.7 ускорение работы кода, сложение огромных 2хмерных массивов

Tags: python, оптимизация, python-2.x

Есть два двумерных массива (например, `ndarray`):

- 3000х4000 (12 000 000 элементов) - 2,5D карта высот - назовем Массив1
- 100Х100 (10 000 элементов) - форма фрезы - назовем Массив2

Задача: нужно обойти "карту высот" "фрезой" и рассчитать 3й массив "оставшийся недорез" для каждого пикселя из Массива1.

Проблема в том, что получается 3000Х4000Х100Х100=**120 000 000 000 точек**, и над каждой нужно провести одну операцию вычитания, одну операцию сравнения на меньше, и несколько операций записи.

Python 2.7 делает это ооочень медленно(на моем компе рассчитывает около 14 часов)

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить работу python скрипта?**

Используемый алгоритм простой:

```
Цикл X по СтрокамМатрицы1: #3000
  Цикл Y по СтрокамМатрицы1: #4000
    Цикл N по СтрокамМатрицы2: #100
      Цикл M по СтрокамМатрицы2: #100
        ВремТочка = матр1[X+N,Y+M] - матр2[N,M]
        Если Матр3[X+N,Y+M] > ВремТочка:
          Матр3[X+N,Y+M] = ВремТочка
```

В реальности есть еще несколько дополнительных операций, но на суть это не влияет.

Вот используемый код:

```
 def get_rmf_map_tool(self,offset_image,tool_roughing,previous_offset,pixelstep_roughing):

        #Dictionary faster then array
        map_tool1 = {}  #numpy.zeros((self.w, self.h), numpy.float32) - self.image.min()
        y = x = 0   #init y,x for speed

        ts_roughing = tool_roughing.shape[0]

        max_line,max_pix = self.get_im_maxmin(self.w, self.h, ts_roughing)

        jrange = self.mxrange(self.row_mill, max_line, pixelstep_roughing)
        irange = self.mxrange(self.row_mill, max_pix)
        ln = max_line

        if prn_detal > 0: print "(Previous tool shape: {0} pixels, max line: {1}, max pixel: {2} )".format(ts_roughing,max_line,max_pix)

        trange = xrange(0,ts_roughing)

        for lin in jrange:    #lines
            progress(lin, ln)
            for pix in irange:    #pixels

                if self.row_mill:
                    y,x = lin,pix
                else:
                    x,y = lin,pix

                m1 = offset_image[y:y+ts_roughing, x:x+ts_roughing]
                hhh1 = (m1 - tool_roughing).max() + previous_offset

                for i in trange:    #lines tool
                    for j in trange:    #pixels tool

                        t = tool_roughing[i,j]
                        if isinf(t): continue

                        ty = i+y
                        tx = j+x
                        # self.image[ty,tx] <= hhh1 !!! t >= 0
                        dt = -self.image[ty,tx] + hhh1 + t
                        #dt = round(dt,16)

                        if dt < -epsilon and prn_detal > -1: print(" delta < -0.00001 ",ty,tx,dt,self.image[ty,tx], hhh1, t)
                        if dt < .0: dt = .0

                        try:
                            if map_tool1[ty,tx] > dt:   #finde MAX for this pixel
                                map_tool1[ty,tx] = dt
                        except KeyError:
                            map_tool1[ty,tx] = dt

        if prn_detal > 0: print "(End make map tool1. Map len: {0} pixels. End at {1})".format(len(map_tool1),datetime.now())
        if len(map_tool1) == 0 and prn_detal > -1: print "(WARNING! Map tool1 len: {0}! )".format(len(map_tool1))
```

Принимаются любые предложения: ассемблер, ctypes, cython, средствами графического процессора, OpenGL, Numpy, CUDA, ... Желательно с примером.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Fast tensor rotation with NumPy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4962606/4279)

Comment: Что такое offset_image ?

Comment: @ReinRaus offset_image это "отступ\зазор" в миллиметрах, который будет оставлен фрезой от карты высот - можно сказать - недорез. Для упрощения можете считать его =0.

Comment: @Alex цикл упростить нельзя, если нет зависимости между offset_image и другими матрицами. Я точно не помню как выглядит, но на листке, который уже выкинул, рассчитывал, что `map_tool1[ty,tx] = (self.image[y:y+ts_routing[0], x:x+ts_routing[0]]- Bm).min() + hhh1` , где Bm это зеркальная матрица к B, и эта формула не упрощается, если offset_image не связан с self.image, а если есть зависимость, то можно еще поразмыслить.

Comment: Я еще нашел способ как цикл 100х100 отдать на вычисление внутрь numpy, это бы дало прирост для чистого питона, но с cython это вряд ли потягается. Хотя... Код цитона она это тоже бы наверно ускорило. Позже выложу как это сделать.

Comment: @ReinRaus огромная благодарность за помощь. Буду признателен, если поможете написать обработку внутри numpy. Я сам думал цикл 100Х100 отдать в numpy, но не смог сделать(док-ция на 300стр). При previous_offset=0 offset_image = self.image, но обычно всегда задают отступ. Практически можно вместо image использовать offset_image, чтобы упростить вычисления, но потом отдельными циклами пройтись по map_tool1[pix,lin] и подобавлять разницы между offset_image и image. Причем добавлять разницы можно опять же внутри numpy.

Comment: Внимательно изучил Вашу формулу и понял идею. Если ей следовать то цикл 100х100 можно заменить так: `map_tool_T[100x100] = offset_image[y:y+ts_roughing,x:x+ts_roughing] - tool_roughing_T`. Где `tool_roughing_T =  tool_roughing - hhh1`. А потом как то поэлементно проверить и сохранить минимальное: `map_tool[y:y+ts_roughing,x:x+ts_roughing] = map_tool_T[100x100].if_min()` как-то так...

Comment: @Alex, там получается, что цикл 100х100 можно заменить на `(матр1-матр2).min()`  причем у матриц размер 100х100, то есть все то же самое, но внутри numpy и плюс еще добавляется накладной расход на срез матрицы.

Comment: @ReinRaus по Вашей формуле матр1 - матр2 создаст матрицу разниц, а функция min() вернет минимальный элемент в этой матрице! А нужно не так. Нужно посчитать матрицу разниц, но потом "обновить" элементы матр1 на те которые меньше соответствующих элементов матр1. Есть ли в нумпи такая функция?

Comment: @Alex на работе зашиваюсь :-( Для интереса прогоните цикл, который не вычисляет значения, а просто помещает в ячейку текст `"B"+str(j)+str(i)+" E"+str(x+j)+str(y+i)` чтобы не вычислять значения, а просто посмотреть какие элементы матриц совместно участвуют для каждой ячейки результата. Там очень интересная зависимость. Е - это матрица значений hhh1. Если сделать зеркальное отражение матрицы В, то все становится очень красиво.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Увы, если ничего принципиально не менять в алгоритме, то разве что средствами графического процессора. На таких данных, пишите вы для процессора хоть на ассемблере, быстро не получится. Вот пример, чтоб не быть голословным:

```
int main()
{
  int i, j, k, l;
  long z = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 300; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 4000; ++j)
      for (k = 0; k < 100; ++k)
        for (l = 0; l < 100; ++l)
          z++;
}
```

Как вы видите, я первый параметр уменьшил в 10 раз (ну допустим вы распараллелите на гипотетические 10 ядер), и вот, что получилось на не самом слабом компьютере:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ time ./test
./test  31,72s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 31,728 total
```

То есть почти 32 секунды, и это на чистом C с минимумом операций. Ну, будет, допустим, 20 секунд на самом современном процессоре, вряд ли это можно назвать быстро.

**Обновление**: написал вашу логику на Cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def calc(
    np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A,
    np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] B,
    np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] C):

    cdef int N1 = A.shape[0]
    cdef int M1 = A.shape[1]
    cdef int N2 = B.shape[0]
    cdef int M2 = B.shape[1]
    cdef int i, j, k, l
    cdef double tp

    if N1 != C.shape[0] or M1 != C.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError('Array dimensions mismatch')

    for k in range(N2):
        for l in range(M2):
            for i in range(N1 - N2):
                for j in range(M1 - M2):
                    tp = A[i + k, j + l] - B[k, l]
                    if C[i + k, j + l] > tp:
                        C[i + k, j + l] = tp
```

Тестовый код (опять в 10 раз меньше данных, чтоб не ждать долго):

```
import numpy as np
import calc

N, M = 300, 4000
n, m = 100, 100

A = np.random.random((N, M))
B = np.random.random((n, m))
C = np.random.random((N, M))

calc.calc(A, B, C)
```

Вот пример запуска:

```
$ time python2 test.py                
python2 test.py  36,68s user 0,05s system 99% cpu 36,734 total
```

То есть ненамного дольше, чем на чистом C. На полных данных точно укладывается в ваше время.

**Обновление 2**: ради интереса запустил на полных данных (массив размера 3000x4000), и получил следующий результат:

```
$ time python2 test.py
python2 test.py  1572,55s user 2,11s system 99% cpu 26:16,10 total
```

В 30 минут уложились, но, конечно, получилось не так быстро, как хотелось бы. Предполагаю, это из-за того, что данные перестали помещаться в кэш. Скорее всего, если разбить большой массив на 10 меньших (которые будут попадать в кэш) и последовательно обработать их, получится гораздо быстрее. Можете попробовать сами, в обработке таких массивов будет пара тонких моментов, так что в рамках ответа на вопрос мне такой код писать лень.

Comment: меня устроит если получиться в пределах 30-50 минут

Comment: @Alex, написал вашу логику на cython, скорости должно хватить с лихвой.

Comment: @Alex, еще раз дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Alex: если есть несколько CPU ядер, то можно отпустить GIL и использовать несколько потоков, например, с помощью [`prange()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/2051661).

Comment: @jfs, да, хорошая идея попробовать, но надо тестировать на практике. При таком распараллеливании вполне может выйти проигрыш по производительности, когда потоки будут затирать кэш друг-другу.

Comment: @VadimShender: **любые** изменения, ради увеличения производительности, необходимо тестировать (даже самые очевидные). И конечно, разный код на разном железе может себя по разному вести.

Comment: @jfs, разумеется, это я больше не вам откомментировал, а топикстартеру, чтобы имел ввиду.

Comment: @VadimShender у автора размеры массива результата больше, чем исходный массив. У Вас они одинаковы. У кого верное поведение?

Comment: @ReinRaus, я не вникал в суть задачи, так как описана она довольно неформально. Я лишь взял псевдокод алгоритма с четырьмя циклами, просмотрев код на Python лишь по диагонали. По всевдокоду размерности `массива1` и `массива3` выходят одинаковыми, единственное, у автора происходит выход за пределы массива из-за индексов `X+N` и `Y+M`, которые достигают 3100 и 4100, соответственно. Это я учел в своем коде. В остальном же любые расхождения вряд ли будут в мою пользу, так как я лишь прикинул, с помощью чего исходный алгоритм можно заставить работать быстрее, не вникая в него.

Comment: Ок, понял. Спасибо. Просто хотел Ваш код включить в свой ответ для эталона правильности, но увидел, что различия есть.

Comment: В "упрощенном" варианте задачи массив1 и массив3 - действительно одной размерности. У меня в коде функция mxrange как раз и корректирует размерность, чтобы в строках ty = i+y и tx = j+x - не выйти за пределы массивов.

Comment: В "полном" варианте массив3 меньше массива1 на размер массива2. Но давайте "полную" задачу пока не рассматривать ввиду того что смысл вопроса от этого не меняется - нужно ускорить алгоритм.